# Upload data in ckan automatically using job scheduler

Tags: upload, jobs, ckan

I have a ckan website.I upload data manually to the datastore, its working perfectly. However my actual requirement is to automate the process.I want a job scheduler which automatically upload data like geojson,excel,csv,pdf,etc in the ckan application.
Please provide inputs

Thanks

Comment: Please describe your manual process that you want automating. i.e. where are your data files currently located, what do you do to upload them, are they new resources, replacements for existing ones, or appended to existing ones

Comment: I upload data by clicking on the Add Dataset then upload data file by click on the upload button in the ckan website. I want to do it automatically by  a scheduler job ,which uploads data after every defined interval.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bash (or python) script that calls the CKAN API using the [ckanapi](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi) program. Use the action function `create_package` or probably more likely `create_resource`. This example, including uploading the file, is in the [ckanapi's README](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi/blob/master/README.md):

```
$ ckanapi resource_create package_id=my-dataset-with-files \
          upload=@/path/to/file/to/upload.csv \
          url=dummy-value  # ignored but required by CKAN<2.6
```

If this is a regular automatable thing then you probably don't want to add a new CKAN dataset each time, as that implies the metadata for that dataset is the same each time, and that doesn't sound helpful for the user - you probably want a new resource each time instead. If the only thing that has changed between each data file is the date, with everything else the same (the purpose, data structure, method of collection, people involved) then it makes more sense to create a single dataset and each update is a new resource in it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't know Python Is it possible to write code in other language like Java and call Ckan rest service to upload and schedule.

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is an HTTP request, as described here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/filestore.html#filestore-api